# How would an increase in temperature affect ooblek's (non newtonian fluid) viscosity?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Due to the fact that Ooblek (cornstarch and water), contains so much water and from what I understand it is non newtonian due to the particles suspended in it, would it therefore be correct to say that as temperature decreases (to non-0 Celsius), the water would freeze and hence raise the ooblek's viscosity?

Would the ooblek's viscosity decrease in higher temperatures as the ooblek's components have more energy and subsequently more space to move in?

Am I correct in this logic?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting to find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the viscosity of a dilatant suspension will decrease if the viscosity of the solvent decreases.

Surprisingly I struggled to find experimental data to back this up. Perhaps everyone thinks it's too obvious to be worth publishing. The best I could do is [this school exeriment report](http://campuspress.yale.edu/chunyangding/files/2015/06/Viscosity-Lab-1560z3z.pdf). The authors timed the fall of a ball through the suspension, so lower viscosity means a shorter fall time. Their results look like:

[image: Fall time vs temp]

Though this isn't a direct measurement of the viscosity it does show that the viscosity falls with increasing temperature.

Note that starch grains start to absorb water and swell at temperatures above 50ºC and when this happens the viscosity will rise dramatically.